# Como añadir Items a un ComboBox apartir de objetos de un ArrayList

Tags: java, netbeans, scenebuilder

Quiero saber como añadir los conductores ya creados al ComboBox de registro de taxis yseleccionar un conductor para despues agregar el taxi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un colega me dijo que podia incluir este codigo en el override y me serviria pero aun asi no funciona.

```
    for (Iterator<Conductor> iterator = lista.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        Conductor next = iterator.next();
        comboBox.getItems().add(next.getNombre());
    }
```

Comment: has probado si lista contiene elementos?

Comment: Creo primero conductores  para luego probar en el taxi pero no aparece nada en el comboBox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se declara la variable de tipo `comboBox`

```
 cbxConductores = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>(); //Esto lo crea automático NetBeans,    
 //pero es importante el nombre de la variable para usarla más adelante
```

Luego realizamos el siguiente método que rellena el `ComboBox`, es importante que reciba un parámetro de tipo `JComboBox`

```
 public void rellenarComboConductores(JComboBox cbxConductores){
            //variable para tomar el nombre
            String nombre;
            //se limpia el combo
            cbxLocal.removeAllItems();//limpia el combobox
            //try por si fallara al momento de rellenar
            try{
                //Se recorre con un for la lista de conductores
                for(int i = 0; i<listaConductores().size(); i++){
                    /**Se le da el valor sacado desde el Array listarConductores
                     * a la variable nombre, la cual recibe la variable nombre
                     * almacenada en el array y se rellena el combobox
                     */
                    nombre = listarConductores().get(i).getNombre();
                    //Se arega un nuevo ítem al combobox
                    cbxLocal.addItem(nombre);
                }
            }catch(Exception e){ //capta el error y lo muestra
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error al cargar ComboBox" + e);
            }
        }
```

Después dentro del método que inicia todos los componentes de la ventana se manda a llamar el método `rellenarComboConductores()` y se le pasa como parámetro el `combobox` de conductores

```
public RegistroTaxiView() throws Exception {
        initComponents();
        rellenarComboLocal(cbxConductores);//<-- manda a llamar al método 
         //y rellena el combo
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Si tu `JComboBox` ya esta creado, crea un array de elementos tipo String a partir de tu lista, usa el método `setModel()` para poblarlo :

```
String[] myArray = lista.toArray(new String[lista.size()]);
comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(myArray));
```

Comment: Todos mis conductores estan siendo guardados en un arrayList llamado listaConductores en una clase llamada cooperativa es la clase principal de la Logica solo quiero que el comboBox muestre el nombre del conductor para que en el taxi se pueda seleccionar pero como te digo no aparece ninguno...

Comment: Luego de seleccionar el nombre del conductor en la lista de conductores con .Equals retorno el objeto para asi ser guardado el taxi tal cual lo piden los parametros